# How to Display hints to user when he is inactive for more than 5 sec in unity?

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

I have made a 2D Game using unity in which user has to select objects of similar color and now i want to display hint when user is unable to select the color for more than four seconds.

I want something similar to candy crush hint displaying system in which candy crush shows hint by highlighting the possible combination if user is not able to identify any combination himself.

I cannot figure out how to find if the user is inactive so that i can display hints.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me in figuring it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mark an answer as correct, there are 2 correct ones...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont agree with Joe Blow on this one that you need to call that EVERYWHERE in your code the user does something. What a user can do is press a key on the keyboard(also count on gamepads and controllers) or move the mouse(on mobile the mouse is simulated so that works too). So if you have a single class that looks something like this :

```
using UnityEngine;
public class TestInActive : MonoBehaviour {
    private Vector3 prevMousePosition = Vector3.zero;
    void ShowGameHintInvoke()
    {
        CancelInvoke();
        Invoke("GameHint", 5);
    }
    void GameHint()
    {
        Debug.Log("This is a Hint");
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.anyKeyDown || Input.mousePosition != prevMousePosition)
            ShowGameHintInvoke();
        prevMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    }
}
```

It should work just  fine. This calls ShowGameHintInvoke() once after the user has been inactive for 5 secs. Then it will not call it again until the user does something.

Comment: This is absolutely a good idea - the OP should certainly do this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTime` type and set it on `Update`, so when the user doesnt do anything, you see all frames if `DateTime` (now) and the saved `DateTime`, the difference is more or equal to 5 seconds, there you show.

If the user touches, you flag that the user had done that, so next frame, you will see he didn't touch, and you set again `DateTime` and start seeing if exceeds 5 seconds.

Do you get what I mean ?

You could use some Coroutines with Yields of 5 seconds ([WaitForSeconds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html)) and you put 5 seconds and if it continues the yield, you show hint.